# Bash script: kill instances before re-executing

Tags: windows, command-line, process, powershell, batch-file

I've got a batch script I use to jump start my development environment. It looks like this

```
:: Update checkout
git pull
:: Compile code with Maven
call mvn clean install -Pui
:: File for a program called Free File Synch which persists changes from one
:: part of the file system (my checkout) to another (the static cache generated
:: by Maven)
source-to-server.ffs_real

:: Navigate to the front-end
cd .\target\frontend
:: Serve to localhost
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

What I'd like to do is kill the process kicked off by `source-to-server.ffs_real` (it's called `RealtimeSync.exe`) — in other words include a kind of teardown before the setup. Elsewhere I've read about `pkill` and `killall` but these aren't available in my PATH. Surely there must be a windows native way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using bash or powershell? Windows or a *nix flavor? Is this bash on a windows box? `pkill` and `killall` are Unix commands.

Comment: Windows, using Powershell. I've got mingw32, ruby, python, and some of the *nix-like commands via git bash. Sorry, I realise my typo — I meant 'batch', not 'bash'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Graceful:

- `taskkill /IM RealtimeSync.exe`

Forced:

- `taskkill /F /IM RealtimeSync.exe`
- `wmic process where name="RealtimeSync.exe" delete`
- `wmic process where name="RealtimeSync.exe" call terminate`